# Why does git detect conflicts in identical lines? Line endings are also identical

Tags: git

This question has apparently been asked often, but the culprit seems to be line endings and whitespace in most cases.

However, I have a case where the line endings are also verifiably identical and there is no other whitespace in the conflicted portion. For example:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
}
=======
}
>>>>>>> develop
```

And a text editor screenshot with line endings displayed:

[image: Identical code conflict with line endings displayed]

both show `↓`, which indicates a `\n` character - it would display `←` for `\r`, and `↵` for `\r\n`.

There is literally no other character besides the identical `}\n` on both sides. Why is this detected as a conflict and how do I avoid it?

Comment: there are more than one sequence of code points can result in the same grapheme. You might want to check what's the encoding behind those two same glyph.

Comment: Yah, your editor is hiding something from you. Look at it with a good programmer's editor, one that can show you actual code points on request. Merge does not report conflicts like this if the lines really are the same.

Comment: What editor would you suggest? This is VSCode with an EOL extension.

Comment: I use vim, it has the `g8` command to show the utf-8 code sequence and `ga` to show the resulting code point value, it's been so long since I used anything else I wouldn't know. emacs is certain to have an equivalent, I just can't recall it at the moment.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say vim, hah. I took a whack at it, despite not knowing it well. The `}` char gives me this output for the commands you suggest, on both sides. `<}>  125,  Hex 7d,  Oct 175, Digr !)`. I'm not sure if it's possible to show similar output for the newline char, but can this really be an issue with that one?

Comment: _probably_ you are working around the EOF... in one file you have a new line then EOF, in the other you don't have the new line. That's enough for git to present you with a conflict.

Comment: If you want to send me your conflicted file, I'll do a hex dump in BBEdit and see if there's a difference your text editor is not showing.

Comment: ha, that's likelier than anything I thought of, great catch @eftshift0

Comment: Yeah, I agree; if this is the last line of the file, that's likely the issue.

Comment: Enough of those conflicts in front of me, @jthill. I can see them coming from veeeeeery far away.

Comment: You're correct that this was right before the EOF. I will see if I can find anything by pulling on that thread. Thanks for the offers to hex dump, I'll see what I can figure out first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are working around the `EOF`, then probably a file has an `EOL` then `EOF`:

```
}<EOL>
<EOF>
```

In the other you do *not* have the `EOL`, just the `EOF`:

```
}<EOF>
```

Or one of them could be:

```
}<EOL>
<EOL>
<EOF>
```

That's enough for git to show a conflict:

- EOL = end of line
- EOF = end of file

Comment: It was indeed that one of the files was missing the final `\n` before the end of the file. One thing that made this hard to catch was that, since both sides of the merge are shown on separate lines, the side on which it was missing had the `\n\` re-added before the ======= or >>>>>>> conflict marker.